# Meta metatables?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to make an __index function in my table which can process ALL of the field it receives.. What I want to do is that if I call the table in the following way

```
mytable.str1.str2.str3
```

I should be able to return the table

```
{"str1", "str2", "str3"}
```

Note that str1,str2,str3 are undefined, they are just strings. I am not trying to create subtables str1, str2, I just want __index to see everything beyond the first period.

Unfortunately what I have seems that __index only captures str1, and complains that "attempt to index field 'str1' (a nil value)"

Anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: You mean you want `{"str1","str2","str3"}`?

Comment: @Stuart P. Bentley: yes, fixed question

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but here's how you do it. The comments explain the trick, but basically you need a second metatable to handle the table that's returned from the first call to the __index metamethod.

If this isn't clear, let me know and I can explain in more detail.

```
-- This metatable appends the new key to itself, then returns itself
stringtablemeta = {}
function stringtablemeta.__index(self, key)
    table.insert(self, key)
    return self
end

-- In response to the question in the comments:
function stringtablemeta.__tostring(self)
    local str = ""
    for i, v in ipairs(self) do
        if i > 1 then str = str .. "-" end
        str = str .. v
    end
    return str
end

-- This metatable creates a new table, with stringmetatable as its metatable
mytablemeta = {}
function mytablemeta.__index(self, key)
    local temp = { key }
    setmetatable(temp, stringtablemeta)
    return temp
end

-- set mytable to have mymetatable as it's metatable. This makes it so when    
-- you index into it, it will call the mytablemeta.__index method.             
--
-- That will return a talb with a single string, the key that was passed
-- in. that table will have it's own metatable, the stringmetatable, which
-- will cause it to append keys that are called on it with its own __index
-- metamethod
mytable = {}
setmetatable(mytable, mytablemeta)

test = mytable.str1.str2.str3

for k, v in pairs(test) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want. You'll get the points as soon as  I can award them. What would be the easiest way to postprocess before assigning? e.g. "test = mytable.str1.str2.str3; print(test)" prints the "str1-str2-str3" (This sounds a roundabout way to achieve something simple...)

Comment: You could either change the stringtablemeta's __index method to append the key to a string every time you call it, or you could add a tostring metamethod. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: I have some directory-like structures. I want an intuitive Lua-like way to access these data structures.

Comment: @Alex: So how would you be able to actually store and retrieve values to/from this table?

Comment: Same way you would any other table. The __index metamethod is only invoked if the table does not have something already on that index. You are free to set fields on your own, only when attempting to index into keys that are nil will `__index` retrieve this special table. Even if that was not the case, it doesn't matter. The requirements were not "make a table that does this specific thing and can be used for generic storage", the requirements were "make a table that does this one specific thing".

Answer (score 1):

It can't. Not without having a metatable on each of those tables.

`mytable` is a table. `str1` is a *different* table. So you can do the same thing by doing this:

```
local temp = mytable.str1
temp.str2.str3
```

And as far as Lua is concerned, these are equivalent. Therefore, the only way to know what was done at each stage is to give *all* of them a special metatable. How you concatenate the different values into a table is something you'll have to investigate on your own.

Comment: I don't actually want to create table str1,str2,str3. I just want the strings.

Comment: well, Alex did the impossible

Comment: @John: No, he did _exactly_ what I said you would have to do: have a metatable on each of those tables. He just found a way to make it semi-automated; it doesn't change the fact that he put a metatable on each of those tables.

Answer (score 1):

As Nicol said, you cannot do that directly in Lua. However, by returning specially crafted tables, you can achieve a similar result to what you want. Take a look at [AutomagicTables](http://lua-users.org/wiki/AutomagicTables) at the Lua-users Wiki for inspiration.